# Multi language react app on IIS server dont work

Tags: reactjs, iis

I deployed a multi language react app, the default language is French, but when I switch to English language from a button in a header, I have the 404 error.
The link to English is : localhost:port/en

In local environement everything is OK, but when I deploy to IIS server I have the 404 error.

I deployed the app by the command **npm run build**, and I take the Build folder and put it in the wwwwroot foler

I don'd find any help in the web.

Thanks

Comment: There's no dedicated react handler so set rewrite rule for something like extensionless URL or not not exist URL would be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I installed the URL Rewrite module on the IIS Server, and I added a web.config file with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>

          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```